Windows on ARM: Math is not trapping
I am using this code to test trapping math on Windows 11, VS2022, amd64 and arm64 systems:
Godbolt
// compile with: cl /O2 /EHa /std:c++20
#include <cfenv>
#include <eh.h>
#include <exception>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void SEFunc()
{
    printf("About to force exception\n");
    float a = 1.0f;
    float b = 0.0f;
    sscanf_s("1.0 0.0", "%f %f", &a, &b);
    float res1 = a / b;  // trapping on amd64, not trapping on arm64
    printf("%f\n", res1);
}

void trans_func(unsigned int, EXCEPTION_POINTERS*)
{
    throw std::exception();
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    _set_se_translator(trans_func);
    unsigned int current_word = 0;
    unsigned int new_word = 0;
    _controlfp_s(&current_word, new_word, _MCW_EM);  // unmask all FP exceptions
    try
    {
        SEFunc();
    }
    catch (const std::exception&)
    {
        printf("Caught an exception\n");
    }
}

The issue is: On amd64 this code works perfectly (trans_func is invoked and exception is thrown during division by zero).
And according to _controlfp_s documentation, trapping should happen as well on ARM (it mentions ARM support multiple times there).
But it doesn't. On ARM (Snapdragon X cpu) this code just silently prints out inf.
I only found small piece of documentation mentioning how windows is silencing ARM math trapping because it did not work on older ARM cpus in the past: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/overview-of-arm-abi-conventions?view=msvc-170#floating-point-exceptions
The question: Am I doing something wrong? Or is it just Microsoft forgetting to update their documentation for _controlfp_s? Maybe somebody can push them to update it?

Try stepping into _control_fp_s to see what it actually going on at hardware level. My first guess was that the optimising compiler had been really clever and precomputed 1.0/0.0 at compile time. But looking at Godbolt that doesn't seem to be the case.

@MartinBrown, thanks. I looked into it and it seems it is really forced trap handle that you cannot get rid of, which just resets FPCR register every time you try to trap.

I tried to look into FPCR values, and it seems by default it is all 0, which means all FP exceptions are not trapping (according to ARM documentation).
If I "enable" trapping for all FP exceptions it becomes 7936 = 0001111100000000, if I enable it for all except "division by zero", it becomes 7424 = 0001110100000000. It checks out with ARM documentation, 9nth bit is "division by zero" bit, FPCR register is correctly controlled by _controlfp_s, but when it comes to actual trapping - something just resets FPCR to 0, disabling all future traps. It seems like windows is forcing this "hidden" trap handler inside, and it seems there is no way to override it.
For example FPCR becomes 0 when you try to divide anything by zero.
Well done, Microsoft! At least you could mention this logic in _controlfp_s documentation!
In short: It seems trapping math is not supposed to work now on new ARM, because Microsoft decided that new ARM cpus have to behave the same way as old, which did not support trapping math.

It is worth reporting it as a defect. At the very least the manual ought to reflect reality.

Yes, I am not really sure how to report it. The only option I see is to propose PR to this page: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/cpp-docs/blob/main/docs/c-runtime-library/reference/controlfp-s.md
I guess I will go with it.

Trapping on floating-point exceptions is an optional feature in the ARMv8-A architecture, so it's possible your CPU model simply doesn't support it.  See A1.5.8 of the Architecture Reference Manual:

For each of the following floating-point exceptions, it is IMPLEMENTATION DEFINED whether an implementation
includes synchronous exception generation: [...]

You could try to find out from Qualcomm whether this is supposed to be a supported feature on the Snapdragon X.  But your experiments with FPCR are consistent with it being unsupported.  From the same source, a few paragraphs lower:

For each floating-point exception that does not support synchronous exception generation, the relevant bit
chosen from FPCR.{IDE, IXE, UFE, OFE, DZE, IOE} is RAZ/WI.

Here "RAZ/WI" means Reads As Zero, Writes Ignored, which sounds like what you're observing.
If this is what's happening, it's not Microsoft's fault that it doesn't work (though ideally they might have mentioned in the documentation that it's contingent on optional hardware support).

this is expected behavior from Windows and Microsoft and should not be an Snapdragon X Elite limitation.

What doy ou mean by "should not be ..."? It is not? It is and you are working on fixing it (because the previous version of this post reads like a support call center default answer)?  You express your disappointment that it is though it should not be?
